# Create column if list of li is higher than ul

Tags: css

If you hover over Menu 1 in my snippet, you can see it contains more list items than the ul can show because its height is only `80px`, how can I create a new "column" so it shows correctly.

Should be:

```
Menu 1
--------------------------------
Menu 1.1    Menu 1.2    Menu 1.3
Menu 1.2    Menu 1.3 
Menu 1.3    Menu 1.1
Menu 1.1    Menu 1.2
```

```css
ul.nav {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

ul.nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

ul.nav > li > ul {
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
ul.nav>li>ul>li>{
  display:block;
}

ul.nav>li>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
}

ul.nav>li>a:hover~ul {
  display: block
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: The most straightforward solution you can use is to add `column-count: 2;column-gap: 0;` to `ul.nav > li > ul` or you can try and set `ul.nav > li > ul` as `display: flex;` and play with its properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the flex properties:

```
ul.nav>li>a:hover~ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```css
ul.nav {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

ul.nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

ul.nav > li > ul {
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
ul.nav>li>ul>li>{
  display:block;
}

ul.nav>li>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
}

ul.nav>li>a:hover~ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3.0</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```